# Ubuntu 17.10 touchpad not precise in small movements

Tags: touchpad, 17.10, hp-touchpad

My mouse works good with the Default acceleration profile. My touchpad instead when starting a movement goes on a perfectly straight line for a bit, then becomes precise again. For example if I draw a little circle on the touchpad, the cursor moves along a square.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on my Lenovo Y700 touchpad using Linux Mint. When I drew a circle on a touchpad my pointer moved along a rounded square. Turning off noise cancellation solved the issue.

```
xinput set-prop "Device ID" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 0 0
```

You can get ID of your touchpad with:

```
xinput list
```

Comment: Yep, this did the trick (Ubuntu 16.04). Thanks!